# Firebase PhoneAuth for Xamarin Android

Tags: firebase, xamarin, nullpointerexception, xamarin.android, firebase-authentication

Even after extensive research, I have been unable to find any implementation of Firebase PhoneAuth for Xamarin Android and I have already tried the answers from other questions similar to mine but those are just C# port of the methods but don't really work. I have tried it but ended up with NullPointerException while calling VerifyPhoneNumber.

LoginActivity.cs

```
...
void VerifyNumber(string mobile_no)
        {
            PhoneAuthCallbacks phoneAuthCallbacks = new PhoneAuthCallbacks();
            PhoneAuthProvider.Instance.VerifyPhoneNumber(mobile_no, 60, Java.Util.Concurrent.TimeUnit.Seconds, this, phoneAuthCallbacks);
        }
        public class PhoneAuthCallbacks : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
        {
            public override void OnVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential)
            {
                FirebaseAuth.Instance.SignInWithCredential(credential);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("onVerificationCompleted");
            }

            public override void OnVerificationFailed(FirebaseException exception)
            {
                // This callback is invoked in an invalid request for verification is made,
                // for instance if the the phone number format is not valid.
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("onVerificationFailed: " + exception);
            }

            public override void OnCodeSent(string verificationId, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken)
            {
                // The SMS verification code has been sent to the provided phone number, we
                // now need to ask the user to enter the code and then construct a credential
                // by combining the code with a verification ID.
                base.OnCodeSent(verificationId, forceResendingToken);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("onCodeSent" + verificationId);
            }
        }
```

Debug Log

```
10-05 16:35:45.265 D/Mono    (19093): Loading reference 8 of /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.App1/files/.__override__/Delivery_DemoApp.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for Xamarin.Firebase.Common, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
10-05 16:35:45.265 D/Mono    (19093): Assembly Ref addref Delivery_DemoApp[0xa7179160] -> Xamarin.Firebase.Common[0xa7177e40]: 2
10-05 16:35:45.265 D/Mono    (19093): Loading reference 1 of /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.App1/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Firebase.Common.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for Mono.Android, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065
10-05 16:35:45.265 D/Mono    (19093): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Firebase.Common[0xa7177e40] -> Mono.Android[0xa7178620]: 12
10-05 16:35:45.265 D/Mono    (19093): Loading reference 9 of /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.App1/files/.__override__/Delivery_DemoApp.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for Xamarin.Firebase.Auth, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
10-05 16:35:45.265 D/Mono    (19093): Assembly Ref addref Delivery_DemoApp[0xa7179160] -> Xamarin.Firebase.Auth[0xa7177d80]: 2
10-05 16:35:45.266 D/Mono    (19093): Loading reference 1 of /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.App1/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Firebase.Auth.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for Mono.Android, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065
10-05 16:35:45.266 D/Mono    (19093): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Firebase.Auth[0xa7177d80] -> Mono.Android[0xa7178620]: 13
10-05 16:35:45.266 D/Mono    (19093): Loading reference 2 of /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.App1/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Firebase.Auth.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for Xamarin.Firebase.Auth.Interop, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
10-05 16:35:45.266 D/Mono    (19093): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Firebase.Auth[0xa7177d80] -> Xamarin.Firebase.Auth.Interop[0xa7177de0]: 2
10-05 16:35:45.266 D/Mono    (19093): Loading reference 2 of /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.App1/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Firebase.Auth.Interop.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for Xamarin.Firebase.Common, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
10-05 16:35:45.266 D/Mono    (19093): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Firebase.Auth.Interop[0xa7177de0] -> Xamarin.Firebase.Common[0xa7177e40]: 3
10-05 16:35:45.266 D/Mono    (19093): Loading reference 0 of /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.App1/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Firebase.Common.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
10-05 16:35:45.266 D/Mono    (19093): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Firebase.Common[0xa7177e40] -> mscorlib[0xa83b5220]: 15
10-05 16:35:45.266 D/Mono    (19093): Loading reference 1 of /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.App1/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Firebase.Auth.Interop.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for Mono.Android, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065
10-05 16:35:45.266 D/Mono    (19093): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Firebase.Auth.Interop[0xa7177de0] -> Mono.Android[0xa7178620]: 14
10-05 16:35:45.266 D/Mono    (19093): Loading reference 0 of /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.App1/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Firebase.Auth.Interop.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
10-05 16:35:45.266 D/Mono    (19093): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Firebase.Auth.Interop[0xa7177de0] -> mscorlib[0xa83b5220]: 16
10-05 16:35:45.266 D/Mono    (19093): Loading reference 3 of /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.App1/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Firebase.Auth.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for Xamarin.Firebase.Common, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
10-05 16:35:45.266 D/Mono    (19093): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Firebase.Auth[0xa7177d80] -> Xamarin.Firebase.Common[0xa7177e40]: 4
10-05 16:35:45.266 D/Mono    (19093): Loading reference 0 of /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.App1/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Firebase.Auth.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
10-05 16:35:45.267 D/Mono    (19093): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Firebase.Auth[0xa7177d80] -> mscorlib[0xa83b5220]: 17
10-05 16:35:45.271 D/Mono    (19093): Loading reference 4 of /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.App1/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Firebase.Auth.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for Java.Interop, Version=0.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065
10-05 16:35:45.271 D/Mono    (19093): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Firebase.Auth[0xa7177d80] -> Java.Interop[0xa7178680]: 6
10-05 16:35:45.271 D/Mono    (19093): Loading reference 10 of /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.App1/files/.__override__/Delivery_DemoApp.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
10-05 16:35:45.272 D/Mono    (19093): Assembly Ref addref Delivery_DemoApp[0xa7179160] -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement[0xa7178140]: 2
10-05 16:35:45.272 D/Mono    (19093): Loading reference 1 of /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.App1/files/.__override__/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for Mono.Android, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065
10-05 16:35:45.272 D/Mono    (19093): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement[0xa7178140] -> Mono.Android[0xa7178620]: 15
10-05 16:35:45.272 D/Mono    (19093): Loading reference 6 of /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.App1/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Firebase.Auth.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
10-05 16:35:45.272 D/Mono    (19093): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Firebase.Auth[0xa7177d80] -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement[0xa7178140]: 3
10-05 16:35:45.273 D/Mono    (19093): Loading reference 0 of /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.App1/files/.__override__/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
10-05 16:35:45.273 D/Mono    (19093): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement[0xa7178140] -> mscorlib[0xa83b5220]: 18
10-05 16:35:45.330 D/Mono    (19093): Loading reference 2 of /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.App1/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Firebase.Common.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for Java.Interop, Version=0.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065
10-05 16:35:45.330 D/Mono    (19093): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Firebase.Common[0xa7177e40] -> Java.Interop[0xa7178680]: 7
10-05 16:35:45.383 D/FirebaseApp(19093): com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId is not linked. Skipping initialization.
10-05 16:35:45.384 D/FirebaseApp(19093): com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
10-05 16:35:45.385 D/FirebaseApp(19093): com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement is not linked. Skipping initialization.
10-05 16:35:45.404 D/Mono    (19093): Loading reference 5 of /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.App1/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Firebase.Auth.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
10-05 16:35:45.405 D/Mono    (19093): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Firebase.Auth[0xa7177d80] -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks[0xa7178200]: 2
10-05 16:35:45.405 D/Mono    (19093): Loading reference 1 of /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.App1/files/.__override__/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for Mono.Android, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065
10-05 16:35:45.405 D/Mono    (19093): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks[0xa7178200] -> Mono.Android[0xa7178620]: 16
10-05 16:35:45.405 D/Mono    (19093): Loading reference 4 of /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.App1/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Firebase.Auth.Interop.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
10-05 16:35:45.405 D/Mono    (19093): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Firebase.Auth.Interop[0xa7177de0] -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks[0xa7178200]: 3
10-05 16:35:45.405 D/Mono    (19093): Loading reference 3 of /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.App1/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Firebase.Common.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
10-05 16:35:45.405 D/Mono    (19093): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Firebase.Common[0xa7177e40] -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks[0xa7178200]: 4
Unhandled Exception: Java.Lang.NullPointerException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>
```

Stack Trace

```
>Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.zza(java.lang.String, long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit, com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider$OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks, android.app.Activity, java.util.concurrent.Executor, boolean)' on a null object reference
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00069] in <3beddfcb1eb547cd8ce47c3097f6eaeb>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x0002a] in <3beddfcb1eb547cd8ce47c3097f6eaeb>:0 
  at Firebase.Auth.PhoneAuthProvider.VerifyPhoneNumber (System.String phoneNumber, System.Int64 timeout, Java.Util.Concurrent.TimeUnit unit, Android.App.Activity activity, Firebase.Auth.PhoneAuthProvider+OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks callbacks) [0x000af] in <fd3fe568403d40c2b79ab43d84a24199>:0 
  at Delivery_DemoApp.Helpers.Firebase_Manager.SendCodeVerification (System.String mobile, Delivery_DemoApp.LoginActivity Instance) [0x00043] in C:\Users\bilka\source\repos\Delivery_DemoApp\Delivery_DemoApp\Helpers\Firebase_Manager.cs:76 
  --- End of managed Java.Lang.NullPointerException stack trace ---
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.zza(java.lang.String, long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit, com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider$OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks, android.app.Activity, java.util.concurrent.Executor, boolean)' on a null object reference
    at com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.zza(Unknown Source:30)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(Unknown Source:10)
    at mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.n_onClick(Native Method)
    at mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.onClick(View_OnClickListenerImplementor.java:30)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6297)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24797)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6626)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
```

Has anyone been able to implement it? If so, please provide assistance

Comment: Found out what is causing the problem. The Firebase Auth is returning null when trying to get the instance from Firebase App. Also, it seems to be a known issue in the current release of Xamarin Firebase Auth. Will have to wait till it gets resolved...

Comment: Hey Bilal! Since you found the solution, could you please put it in as an answer below, so that this question can be closed, and so others can find the solution easily when they are looking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As found earlier, this is a known issue with the new Xamarin Firebase Auth package where the Firebase Auth instance is null, details of which can be found at https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues/223.

A temporary fix is also mentioned (which has indeed solved my issue, at least for sign up and login functions) as shown below

```
var instance = FirebaseAuth.GetInstance(app);
if (instance == null)
{
    instance = new FirebaseAuth(app);
}
```

Comment: You could make the solution as answer to make answer searching easier and be beneficial to community members. Thank you~

Comment: Salaam Bilal, can I have your email?

Answer (score 0):

As it appears this is still an issue in the current Xamarin Firebase Auth package. Building on from Bilal's solution I have found a way to get Phone Auth working. You can use the `FirebaseAuth` instance to get a `PhoneAuthProvider` instance.

```
var instance = FirebaseAuth.GetInstance(FirebaseApp.GetInstance(FirebaseApp.DefaultAppName));
if (instance == null)
{
    instance = new FirebaseAuth(FirebaseApp.GetInstance(FirebaseApp.DefaultAppName));       
}

var providerInstance = PhoneAuthProvider.GetInstance(instance);
providerInstance.VerifyPhoneNumber(numberWithCode, 60, Java.Util.Concurrent.TimeUnit.Seconds, this, PhoneAuthCallbacks);
```

Hopefully this helps someone